# How to use action listeners to run designated methods on seperate input

Tags: java, user-interface, panel, actionlistener

I am nearly done with the backend work for a small app I am making to help me give out construction estimates.

There are four input fields (2 drop-down, 2 text input) and a button at the bottom which is meant to sum up the results and provide a total. The variables have already been tuned such that it will give me the right answer under the action listener. The action listener is connected to the button. The calculate button has not been working despite trying a few different ways.

Am I using action listener right in this context?

```java
package packagepackage;

import java.util.*;
import packagepackage.HintTextFieldUI; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
public class CP_GUI extends JFrame {
    
    public JTextField linear; 
   public JComboBox<String> sump; 
   public JComboBox<String> elec; 
    public JTextField prep; 
    public JButton calculate; 
   public JLabel estimate; 
    
     public CP_GUI() {  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        int subTotal = 0;
        
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(400, 400, 100, 100));
        
        
        linear = new JTextField();
        panel.add(linear);
        
        prep = new JTextField();
        panel.add(prep);
        
        String[] sumpo = {"New sump pump","Existing sump pump"};
        sump = new JComboBox<>(sumpo);
        panel.add(sump);
        
        String[] electo = {"There is an outlet within 6 feet of sump pump","There is no outlet nearby, or I do not need a new one"};
        elec = new JComboBox<>(electo);
        panel.add(elec);
      
        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String lins = linear.getText();
                Integer linVar = Integer.parseInt(lins);
                linVar *= 13;
                
                Object sumps = sump.getSelectedItem();
                Integer sumpVar = 0;
                if("New sump pump".equals(sumps)) {
                    sumpVar += 260;}
                
                Object elecs = elec.getSelectedItem();
                Integer elecsVar = 0;
                if("There is an outlet within 6 feet of the sump pump".equals(elecs)) {
                    elecsVar += 280;}
                
                String preps = prep.getText();
                Integer prepsVar = Integer.parseInt(preps);
                prepsVar += 1;
                prepsVar *= 110;
                
                Integer subTotal = linVar += sumpVar += elecsVar += prepsVar;
                /* overhead*/
                subTotal += 2428;
                /* tax */
                subTotal *= 11;
                subTotal /= 10;
                /* margin */
                subTotal *= 12;
                subTotal /= 10;
                    }
        });
        

        panel.add(calculate);
        estimate = new JLabel();
        String inWords =  String.valueOf(subTotal);
        estimate.setText(inWords);
        panel.add(estimate);
       
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        String title = "Drain Tile Calculator";
        frame.setTitle(title);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        linear.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Perimeter length", true));
        prep.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Hours of preptime", true));
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CP_GUI();
    }        
}
```

Basically, I am just curious if anyone knows which part I'm messing up on. I appreciate any help!

Edit: Thanks for the tip on elecsVar! I fixed the issue
but the label still does not appear on the GUI when I
press the button. Am I hiding the result? Here is what it looks like now, although the 0 does not change.

[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyzC0.png)

Comment: Why do you cast `Integer elecsVar = (Integer) elecs`, if `elecs` is a String from the combo box?  That's the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you think that when you calculate a new subtotal (after the user presses the *Calculate* button) that the text of the `JLabel` will update automatically. If you were using JavaFX for your GUI (rather than *Swing*) then you may be able to set up a binding for that. But since you are using *Swing*, you need to explicitly update the `JLabel` text, in method `actionPerformed`, after calculating the new subtotal.

Here is your code with required changes. I just added two lines at the end of method `actionPerformed`. Note that I couldn't find code for class `HintTextFieldUI` so I commented out those lines.

```java
//import HintTextFieldUI;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CP_GUI extends JFrame {

    public JTextField linear;
    public JComboBox<String> sump;
    public JComboBox<String> elec;
    public JTextField prep;
    public JButton calculate;
    public JLabel estimate;

    public CP_GUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        int subTotal = 0;
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(400, 400, 100, 100));
        linear = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(linear);
        prep = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(prep);
        String[] sumpo = {"New sump pump", "Existing sump pump"};
        sump = new JComboBox<>(sumpo);
        panel.add(sump);
        String[] electo = {"There is an outlet within 6 feet of sump pump",
                           "There is no outlet nearby, or I do not need a new one"};
        elec = new JComboBox<>(electo);
        panel.add(elec);
        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String lins = linear.getText();
                Integer linVar = Integer.parseInt(lins);
                linVar *= 13;

                Object sumps = sump.getSelectedItem();
                Integer sumpVar = 0;
                if ("New sump pump".equals(sumps)) {
                    sumpVar += 260;
                }

                Object elecs = elec.getSelectedItem();
                Integer elecsVar = 0;
                if ("There is an outlet within 6 feet of the sump pump".equals(elecs)) {
                    elecsVar += 280;
                }

                String preps = prep.getText();
                Integer prepsVar = Integer.parseInt(preps);
                prepsVar += 1;
                prepsVar *= 110;

                Integer subTotal = linVar += sumpVar += elecsVar += prepsVar;
                /* overhead */
                subTotal += 2428;
                /* tax */
                subTotal *= 11;
                subTotal /= 10;
                /* margin */
                subTotal *= 12;
                subTotal /= 10;
                String inWords = String.valueOf(subTotal);
                estimate.setText(inWords);
            }
        });
        panel.add(calculate);
        estimate = new JLabel();
        String inWords = String.valueOf(subTotal);
        estimate.setText(inWords);
        panel.add(estimate);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        String title = "Drain Tile Calculator";
        frame.setTitle(title);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

//        linear.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Perimeter length", true));
//        prep.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Hours of preptime", true));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CP_GUI();
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the GUI when it is initially displayed.

[image: initial display]

And here it is after entering values into the `JTextField`s and pressing `Calculate` button.

[image: after calculate]

Note that the `JLabel` appears below the `JComboBox` since your `JPanel` is using [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).